# Unexpected parameter marker when trying to run my stored procedure

Tags: java, android, sql-server, stored-procedures

so i be getting a

> Unexpected parameter marker at position 40

when i try to run my stored procedure 
which is the

```
   BEGIN //line 40 
   RETURN 1010
   END
```

i am not exactly sure what that one does and if it has something to do with the way i had decalred the values in the code
the code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (userid.trim().equals("Developer")|| password.trim().equals("Dev!n_234"))
            isSuccess2=true;
        z = getString(R.string.login_succes);
        if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
            z = getString(R.string.indsæt_rigtigt_bruger);
        else
        {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = getString(R.string.Forbindelses_fejl)+"L1)";

                } else {
                    String query = "{call [system].[usp_validateUserLogin](?,?,?,?,?)}";
                    CallableStatement ps = con.prepareCall(query);
                    ps.setString(1, userid);
                    ps.setString(2, password);
                    ps.setInt(3,72);
                    ps.setNull(4, Types.BOOLEAN);
                    ps.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    if(rs.next())
                    {

                        z = getString(R.string.login_succes);

                        isSuccess=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        z = getString(R.string.Invalid_Credentials);
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = getString(R.string.Exceptions)+"L2)";
                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", ex);
            }
        }
        return z;

    }
}
}
```

the stored procedure

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [system].[usp_validateUserLogin]
        @p_Login NVARCHAR ( 50 )
        , @p_Password NVARCHAR ( 32 )
        , @p_CompanyID INT
        , @p_OutDetails BIT = 1
        , @p_AuthenticationTicket VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @errNo INT
            , @recCount INT
            , @res INT

        SELECT u.*
            INTO #tmpLogin
        FROM system.[User] AS u WITH ( NOLOCK )
        WHERE ( u.Login = @p_Login )
            AND ( u.Company_ID = @p_CompanyID )
            AND ( pwdcompare ( @p_Password, u.Passwd ) = 1 )
            AND ( u.Status = 0 ) --Active

        SELECT @errNo = @@ERROR
            , @recCount = @@ROWCOUNT

        IF ( @errNo <> 0 )
        BEGIN
            RETURN 1010
        END

        IF ( @recCount = 1 )
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @userID INT
            SELECT @userID = ID
            FROM #tmpLogin

            EXEC @res = system.usp_renewAuthenticationTicket @p_DoerTicket = ''
                                                            , @p_AuthenticationTicket = @p_AuthenticationTicket OUTPUT
                                                            , @p_UserID = @userID
                                                            , @p_CompanyID = @p_CompanyID
            IF ( @res <> 0 )
                RETURN @res

        END
        --SET @p_AuthenticationTicket = 'TESTAUTHENTICATIONTICKET0123456789'

        IF ( @p_OutDetails = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM #tmpLogin
        END

        RETURN 0
    END
```

my old code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
else
{
try {
Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
if (con == null) {
z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
} else {
String query = "select * from Usertbl where UserId='" + userid + "' and password='" + password + "'";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

if(rs.next())
{

z = "Login successfull";
isSuccess=true;
}
else
{
z = "Invalid Credentials";
isSuccess = false;
}

}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
isSuccess = false;
z = "Exceptions";
}
}
return z;
}
}
```

Comment: not sure if there is any error in your SP, but I prefer to save my return codes in one RC variable and make one exit only at the end of the SP returning this RC.

Comment: there shouldn't be any error in the SP as it is working on our main program

Comment: I assume "position 40" is the character position in query string (where parenthesis starts). This is for sure client-side error, your sp is not executed. Note, you are calling `executeQuery` before `prepareCall`.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some issues here.  As Ivan Starostin pointed out, you call `executeQuery` before `prepareCall`.  Also:

```
CallableStatement cs = null; // This variable is cs
String query = "{call [system].[usp_validateUserLogin] (?,?,?,?,?)}";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); // I assume the error is here because you're executing an empty statement
CallableStatement ps = con.prepareCall(query); // Then you make another CallableStatement called ps
ps.setString(1, userid);
// other stuff with ps
cs.executeUpdate(); // Then you ignore ps and call cs, which is null
```

One of the skills you'll need as a programmer is the ability to look at your code line by line and figure out what it's doing.  If you had looked carefully through your code you should have seen these issues.  I don't mean to be harsh, just trying to get you to think about how to deal with these issues in the future, because they will come up over and over.  Everyone makes coding mistakes, that's no big deal, we just have to learn how to spot them when things go wrong.

Comment: i had tryed to work around with it and changeing cs to ps gaved me the same error and move `Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);` to after execute update gaved me null pointer or by using just `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(query);`
Use of the executeQuery(String) method is not supported on this type of statement
so i am abit lost here

the problem is that i had it to run in my old code with out any issues where i had typed statement but i am trying to do it from our sp and i am not sure how to get it to work with my structure

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying things without understanding what they do.  Do you know what each of the lines in your method does?